# trouble with "statistics" property when using with YouTube.Search.list in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I cannot seem to get this script to work for 'statistics':

```
function searchByKeyword2() {
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('statistics', {q: 'dogs', maxResults: 5, });
  for(var i in results.items) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    Logger.log(item);
  }
}
```

I can use 'id', 'snippet', or 'id, snippet', but I cannot get it to work with 'statistics'.  I've been looking an answer for hours, but I haven't found anything.  Any clues?

Comment: That's because `statistics` is not a valid parameter for a [`YouTube.Search` Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#properties) while `id` and `snippet` are. Perhaps you meant to use [`YouTube.Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)?

Comment: I see now.  So would the solution be to collect all of the id values with YouTube.Search.list and then put them into YouTube.Videos.list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the API documentation, [`YouTube.Search`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) includes results for [`Video`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)s, [`Channel`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels)s, and [`Playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists)s. Not all of these resources have statistics nodes, and thus the `YouTube.Search` endpoint does not allow querying for the `statistics` node - only `id` and `snippet`.

For collections which track `statistics`, like `Video`s, you query them directly to access `statistics`. Since [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) does not search, you need to first search and then provide the relevant video IDs. Note that you can change the search order (and many other search properties) - full details available in the API reference - but the default sort is 'relevance'.

As an example:

```
function getVideoStatistics(videoIds) {
  const options = {
    id: videoIds.join(","),
    fields: "nextPageToken,items(id,statistics)"
  };

  const results = [];
  do {
    var search = YouTube.Videos.list('statistics', options);
    if (search.items && search.items.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(results, search.items);
    options.pageToken = search.nextPageToken;
  } while (options.pageToken);

  return results;
}

function getVideosFromQuery(query, maxResults) {
  const options = {
    q: query,
    maxResults: maxResults,
    type: 'video',
    fields: "nextPageToken,pageInfo/totalResults,items(id/videoId,snippet(title,channelTitle))"
  };
  const results = [];
  do {
    var search = YouTube.Search.list('snippet', options);
    if (search.items && search.items.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(results, search.items);
    options.pageToken = search.nextPageToken;
  } while (options.pageToken && results.length < search.pageInfo.totalResults && results.length < maxResults);

  return results;
}

function foo() {
  var someQuery = "something";
  var searchResults = getVideosFromQuery(someQuery, 50);
  var ids = searchResults.map(function (videoSearchResult) {
    return videoSearchResult.id.videoId;
  });
  var stats = getVideoStatistics(ids);
  console.log({message:"query video statistics", searchResults: searchResults, statistics: stats});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'll try to get this going asap.

Comment: @gg-edu ah, `channelTitle` is under snippet - needed to either use `snippet(title,channelTitle)` or `snippet/title,snippet/channelTitle`. Good catch!